# Mysql update database using changed datagrid c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I trying learn using WPF application to connect and edit database. I newibe on c# programming. I have connect do database and bind result into datagrid.

```
 public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            dataTable = new DataTable("dzialy");
            mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                //mySqlConnection.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from dzialy", mySqlConnection);
                mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                mySqlCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
                mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                mySqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
                mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
                 ds = new DataSet();
                 mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                 mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
                 dataGridCustomers.DataContext = ds;

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                //mySqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

On datagrid I easy change value from database. This is possible to send changed datagrid to database?

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest you if you start with C# / WPF you begin to use MSSQL instead of MySQL, There are a lot of examples out there on the internet that use MSSQL with Entity Framework. Entity Framework is an OR Mapper. This Maps the Rows in your Database table to an Object in code C#
These are called Entities.

If you use Entity Framework you can use LINQ that is a language you can use that you write in C#. These queries will be translated by Entity Framework to real SQL queries.

For example if you take your code 
you can rewrite this like so

```
using(var context = new EntitiesContext())
{
   var entities = context.Dzialies.ToList();
}
```

The code above is to select all your rows inside the table dzialy.
and can now set the entities to your `dataGridCustomer`.
I Would recommend you to take a look the following link to get started

[Click ME!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683942/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-for-understanding-E)

This absolute beginners guide to Entity Framework is used along side ASP.net MVC but it's mostly the same with WPF. I hope this helps you in your search.